# ZK proof of committed value

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

I'm looking for a scheme that a prover can commit to a value $d$, via a commitment $C$, while also provide ZK-proof that this value $d$, together with a public key $e$, are RSA pairs. (i.e private and public key respectively).

Thanks.

Comment: The public key is a commitment, why would you need an extra commitment. Are you asking for proof of ownership of an RSA private key?

Comment: I want to bind the private key with the commitment $C$. in order that the prover will have to show $d$ in the reveal phase.

Comment: Public key (e,n) should be enough of a commitment. Or I'm missing something.

Comment: Probably it's "Deep coin" paper of Guillou and Quisquater,
Eurocrypt 88.